# How to debug a script using the module logging

Tags: python, logging

I have a script using several imported submodules of mine, each of them using the module logging. In 1 of them i wrote a bad code line, but i can figure out where it is. Indeed, the synthax for a typical logging output with an argument var is:

```
logging.info("my var=%s", var)
```

If the number of arguments does not correspond to the number of %s in the string, there is an error message from logging as follows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 776, in emit
  msg = self.format(record)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 654, in format
  return fmt.format(record)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 436, in format
  record.message = record.getMessage()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 306, in getMessage
  msg = msg % self.args
ValueError: incomplete format
```

The problem is that this error message is completely generic: it does not show the name of the module where the probleme appear, nor the code line, nor the arguments... which makes impossible for me to find out where I wrote a bad call to logging.info()

Comment: In Python 2.7 and later, you should get a message indicating where the line was logged from (Issue #7869, fixed in February 2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q&D braindead solution : edit /usr/lib/python2.6/logging/**init**.py and wrap line 776 in a try/except clause:

```
try:
    msg = self.format(record)
except ValueError:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

then re-run your code from a shell and do whatever needed to re-raise the exception. You'll be sent in the step debugger, from which you can inspect the whole call stack.

Once the problem solved, rollback your edits. And eventually contribute a patch to the `logging` module so it emits a more useful error message...

Oh and BTW : automated tests are a good way to catch this kind of errors as soon as possible, when you remember what part of the code you just touched.

Comment: Thanks. Editing logging/init.py was actually my first idea... but i do not have root permissions on my machine :(

Comment: How can one not have root permissions on one's own machine ??? I don't know where you're working but be sure I'll never work there. But anyway: nothing prevents you from getting the `logging` package's sources (it's pure Python AFAICT) and copy it locally so it's in your `sys.path`.

Comment: in any university for example, it is probably the case :)

Comment: In Python 2.7 and later, you should get a message indicating where the line was logged from (Issue #7869, fixed in February 2010).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
logging.info("my var=%s" % var)
```

Comment: The comma will work just fine since the logging function will do replacements

Comment: my problem is that i have already 1000's of code lines in several modules, using the synthax logging.info("my var=%s", var), which works pretty well, except that at one (unknown) place, the number of arguments does not fit the number of %s... And i would like another solution than checking each lline of code...

Comment: what is inside variable var ?

Comment: it could be anything, sometimes a INT sometimes a str. In this precise case, i don't know since i don't know where is the bug in the code. MY question is how can i bypass the fact that the error message of the module logging are unsuable.

Comment: @Peter: this kind of defeat part of the point of using the `logging` module, as it will perform the string formatting regardless of the current logging level.